# Как убрать артефакты на изображении?

Tags: java, android, opengl, libgdx

При создании игры на LibGDX в пиксельном оформлении столкнулся с появлением артефактов по всему изображению. Артефакты появляются на местах, где происходит смена цвета, причём только на Android. На Windows всё рисует хорошо.
[image: Скриншот на Android]

Фильтрация текстур Nearest. Если сделать Linear то изображение становится слегка мыльным, что мне не надо. Конечно, картинка немного растягивается на Android.

Текстурки загружаются через TextureAtlas. Вывожу на экран TextureRegion через SpriteBatch. Картинка на экране никуда не двигается.

Некоторые файлы и атлас текстур из игры: https://yadi.sk/d/34b5Bp6ysvcyq
Часть кода из класса, унаследованного от Game:

```
static final float GAME_WIDTH = 640.0f;
static final float GAME_HEIGHT = 360.0f;

float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

Gdx.app.log("Width", screenWidth + " ");
Gdx.app.log("Height", screenHeight + " ");

scale = GAME_WIDTH / screenWidth;
Gdx.app.log("Scale", scale + " ");
gameWidth = GAME_WIDTH;
gameHeight = screenHeight * scale;

cam = new OrthographicCamera();
cam.setToOrtho(true, gameWidth, gameHeight);


delta_cam = (GAME_WIDTH - GAME_HEIGHT) / 2;
delta_ass = (gameWidth - gameHeight) / 2;
delta_scr = delta_cam - delta_ass;

Assets.load((int) delta_ass, (int) gameHeight, (int) gameWidth);
Settings.load();

batch = new SpriteBatch();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
```

Comment: Написали очень поверхностно, кода нету, проблему решить трудно. Даже минимум где артефакт... А ваще артефакты могут появлятся при отсутствии синхронизации вертикальной vsync. Думаю понели о чем я.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров vsync здесь не играет роли, т.к. картинка не движется. Артефакты под каждой буквой, и даже не фоне можно заметить. Отрисовка изображения через SpriteBatch.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос оригинал текстуры, это будет крайне полезно

Comment: @Unick добавил текстуры. Если нужны ещё какие либо файлы, скажите мне.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на дизеринг (dithering) - попытки растеризовать с учетом частичного перекрытия пикселей.

Проверьте что у вас все попиксельно в координатах всех спрайтов выверено и все размеры совпадают. Например - что спрайт 12 * 16 рисуется ровно в 60 * 80, а не 60,125 * 80,2375.

P.S. Смущает, что в правой палке буквы П на один пиксель меняется ширина, как будто какой-то скос идет. Понять в чем дело не зная вашего процесса отрисовки - нельзя.

Comment: Я использую libGDX для отрисовки. Текстура действительно мастабируется, и получаются такие артефакты. Как можно изменить процесс растеризации так, что бы пиксели отрисовывались в наиболее близком им положении?

Answer (score -2):

Не знаю как это работает.. но я увеличил размер игрового экрана на 0,1:

```
static final float GAME_WIDTH = 640.1f;
static final float GAME_HEIGHT = 360.1f;
```

И на телефоне пропали все такие артефакты. <strike>костыль года</strike>